# Removing value from another figure not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone have any ideas why the entered deposit value is not deducting from the total value here?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#invoice_table').on('input', '.calculate', function () {
        calculateTotal();
    });

    function calculateTotal() {
        // calculate deposit
        var total = parseInt($('#invoice_total').val()) || 0,
            deposit = parseInt($('#invoice_deposit').val()) || 0;
        var calcDeposit = total - deposit;
        $('#invoice_total').val((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="invoice_table">
    <input type="text" name="invoice_discount" id="invoice_discount" value="" class="calculate" />
    <input type="text" name="invoice_total" id="invoice_total" value="1000" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fn6L2eqp/2/

Comment: What's `$('#invoice_deposit')`?

Comment: Please update your fiddle with the above comment.

Comment: opps sorry, updated http://jsfiddle.net/fn6L2eqp/4/ - however type 500 and does not change total to 500 for some reason...

Comment: How about using the change event instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fn6L2eqp/5/) for you,

You were overwriting the value set in the `invoice_total` text box.

I have added a `<span>` to display the result instead.

This way you get the result you want.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would want the js to be http://jsfiddle.net/fn6L2eqp/2/ :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#invoice_table').on('change', '.calculate', function () {
        calculateTotal();
    });

    function calculateTotal() {
        // calculate deposit
        var total = parseInt($('#invoice_total').val()) || 0,
            deposit = parseInt($('#invoice_discount').val()) || 0;
        var calcDeposit = total - deposit;
        $('#invoice_total').val((calcDeposit).toFixed(2));
    }

});
```

Comment: thats exactly what he has